# How long does it take normally for brokers to add new stocks? For example, $PECK just came out today 6/20/19

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

Robinhood added $PECK before Webull did, but what's the minimum time for it come out? Looking for an answer like in hours, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

With most mainstream brokers, for new issues to be traded on the major exchanges, the symbol is available when trading goes live.  Second tier brokers can be sketchy.

When it comes to grey market issues, sometimes you have to contact a broker's trading desk to get them to get the symbol into their system.  Some are faster than others at this.